# Chaining a list of member functions where one member function's call depends on if boolean is true or false

Tags: c++, chaining

We have a class that is defined with chained member functions, and it is intended to be called like this

```
    Tensor().setA(args)
    .setB(args)
    .setC(args)
    .setD(args)
    .build();
```

But sometimes (if `flag == true`), we call it with this

```
    Tensor().setA(args)
    .setB(args)
    .setC(args)
    .setD(args)
    .setE(args)
    .build();
```

So currently, I have

```
if (flag == true) {
  return Tensor().setA(args)
    .setB(args)
    .setC(args)
    .setD(args)
    .setE(args)
    .build();
} else {
  return Tensor().setA(args)
    .setB(args)
    .setC(args)
    .setD(args)
    .build();
}
```

which seems there's some unnecessary duplicate code and I'm looking for suggestions on how to remove the duplication.

One method I though to is

```
auto temp = Tensor().setA(args)
    .setB(args)
    .setC(args)
    .setD(args);
if (flag == true) {
    temp.setE(args)
}
return temp.build();
```

but I'm not totally sure this won't slow down the pre-existing implementation.

Is it possible to do something like this (I know this is not valid C++ but I'm trying to illustrate a point)

```
return temp = Tensor().setA(args)
    .setB(args)
    .setC(args)
    .setD(args);
    (flag == true ? .setE(args) : do nothing)
    .build();
```

`Tensor` here is the class name (apologies for omitting this really important detail)

Comment: There is no way to conditionally call the member function in the expression without replicating everything in a conditional operator equivalently to your original `if` approach. Why do you think that your alternative working solution might have a performance impact? The only part I am  not sure about is why `temp` is needed. Shouldn't operating on `Tensor` be sufficient?

Comment: Additionally, the proposed plan of action creates a copy of the original object. It is fairly like that each one of the methods returns `*this`. An unexpected copy of an object nearly always ends in tears.

Comment: @user17732522 I was concerned about maybe it might cause additional copies, but it seems it won't; however, I just tried it and it didn't compile. I think we have some restrictions for this particular class that doesn't let us create the initial `temp` because it doesn't call `build()`. I think we'd have to call `build()` twice, which I think would definitely have performance impact. 

I think I'll just stick with the original approach

Comment: @roulette01 Well, why is `temp` there at all? Just remove `auto temp = ` and use `Tensor` everywhere.

Comment: Is `Tensor` maybe intended to be the type and it should be `Tensor{}` everywhere in the code snippets?

Comment: Also, while you cannot conditionally call the member function as part of the expression, you can of course call another function taking a reference and conditionally calling the member function on the reference. It will just look a bit inconsistent with the syntax of the other calls.

Comment: How about `return Tensor.setA(args).setB(args).setC(args).setD(args).setE(flag ? args : 0).build()`? Assume the default value of `E` is `0`.

Comment: It is the builder pattern. But some details are unclear: What is `Tensor`? A class or a variable? Are the set functions static member functions?

Comment: Just updated the OP. Sorry, `Tensor` here is actually the class name, and it should have been `Tensor{}` or `Tensor()`, not just `Tensor`. Sorry about that

Comment: I think the first version would not slow it down. You can optionally always use `temp.` instead of chaining to make the `if` block more similar to the unconditional lines.

Comment: @Sebastian I think the `if/else` approach probably gets optimized away so yeah I don't think there's any performance hit. I was just concerned about the code duplication, but I think that's a rather trivial detail.

Comment: I meant the other one, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a do-nothing method to `Tensor` with the same signature as `setE()`, you can do something like this:

```
Tensor& (Tensor::*setEOrNoOp)(argTypes) = flag? &Tensor::setE : &Tensor::noOp;

(Tensor{}
    .setA(args)
    .setB(args)
    .setC(args)
    .setD(args)
    .*setEOrNoOp)(args)
    .build();
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/iHfkes)

If altering `Tensor` is not an option, then you can use a wrapper function/lambda instead:

```
Tensor& doSetE(Tensor &t, argTypes args)
{
    return t.setE(args);
}

Tensor& doNoOp(Tensor &t, argTypes)
{
    return t;
}

Tensor& (*setEOrNoOp)(Tensor&, argTypes) = flag? &doSetE : &doNoOp;

setEOrNoOp(
    Tensor{}
    .setA(args)
    .setB(args)
    .setC(args)
    .setD(args)
    , args)
    .build();
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/WQzHvc)

Comment: I would rename `temp` in the first code to something like `setE_optional`

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of discouraged for me to make any modifications to `Tensor`. I think I might just keep my original `if/else` approach. I think the code duplication is a bit easier to read than defining the lambda? Probably subjective, but that's my initial impression

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the cleanest way to the eyes.

```
Tensor t;
t.setA(args);
t.setB(args);
t.setC(args);
t.setD(args);
if (flag)
    t.setE(args);
return t.build();
```